# Setting TabIndex efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more efficient way to write this? Seems redundant to me:

```
    var leaves = $(".leaf");
    var trees = $(".tree");

    $(".my-class").on("click", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass("leaf")) {
            trees.each(function() {
                $(this).attr("tabIndex", -1);
            });
            leaves.each(function() {
                $(this).attr("tabIndex", 1);
            });
        } else {
            trees.each(function() {
                $(this).attr("tabIndex", 1);
            });
            leaves.each(function() {
                $(this).attr("tabIndex", -1);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) can work on all jQuery matched elements at once.

Assuming that performance isn't a concern, I think that the clearest way would be to "reset" all nodes to have a `tabIndex` of `-1` first.

```
var leaves = $(".leaf");
var trees = $(".tree");

$(".my-class").on("click", function(e) {
    leaves.add(trees).attr("tabIndex", -1);

    var selected = $(e.target).hasClass("leaf") ? leaves : trees;
    selected.attr("tabIndex", 1);
});
```

Comment: Apologies.  I made a typo --the correction is above. The conditionals are actually different.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass("leaf")) {
    // do x
} else {
    // do x but in a different way
}
```

This part makes it harder to maintain. If you change one you must change the other.

```
$(this).attr("tabIndex", -1);
```

You do not need jQuery for this. Try `this.setAttribute("tabIndex", -1)` or even `this.tabIndex = -1`.

Also, I see some problems with this code:

1. Why are you checking the event's target in `$().on("click")`? Would the event's target not be `this`? Maybe you should change it to `$(".leaf.my-class, .tree.my-class")`?
2. What if a user clicks on an element besides `.leaf` or `.tree`? The code suggests that you expect one or the other. Should `$(".my-class")` be changed to `$(".leaf, .tree")`?
3. What if you add leaves? You will need to update `leaves` and `trees` if new leaves/trees are created.

Here is my proposed solution...

```
var $leaves = $(".leaf"), $trees = $(".tree"), tabIndexLeaves = -1, tabIndexTrees = 1;
$(".my-class").on("click", function (e) {
    var isLeaf = $(e.target).hasClass("leaf");
    if ((isLeaf && tabIndexLeaves !== 1) || (!isLeaf && tabIndexLeaves === -1)) {
        // Invert the tabIndex
        tabIndexLeaves = -tabIndexLeaves;
        tabIndexTrees = -tabIndexTrees;
        // Update all the leaves' and trees' tabIndexes
        $leaves.attr("tabIndex", "" + tabIndexLeaves);
        $trees.attr("tabIndex", "" + tabIndexTrees);
    }
});
```